# What is this screeching noise?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, horror, screams

There is this sound commonly used in trap / rap beats where a screech is sometimes present in the background. It is usually an effect to help set the theme for a song. In the scenario, it is a more creepy dark theme. I have an example to show you what the sound is.

At around **26 seconds** the sound I am curious about, appears.

Comment: Probably just a synth, probably fm, with a highpass and maybe some distortion. I'll make a better answer when i have time

Comment: Sure thing, would there be a certain source in which I can find this sound?

Comment: I don't understand. I was saying any FM synth. FM from Native Instruments is a good one, or any from this list of free ones https://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/09/12/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-fm-synthesizer-vstiau-plugins/. You could probably get by with any subtraction synth too. What DAW are you using? It probably has a synthesizer that would would.

Comment: OR! You could google "Trap music stab" (or Sweep, or something like that) on a free sound effects website if you don't want to make one yourself.

Comment: Okay... I Google it, and the results I have found, seem to be as if I searched something totally different.

Comment: Sorry, I meant search on a SFX site not google. I couldn't find anything with those keywords either. Gonna make an answer below now.

Answer (score 1):

It's the sampled scream that plays in the very beginning. It's pitched up, or rather played through a sampler instrument which would map the sample to multiple notes on the keyboard.

It does not sound like a synth, as some of the other answers have suggested.

Comment: Would there be somewhere to download this?

Comment: You would have to know where the sample came from. It kind of sounds like it could be from a movie, but it's always possible that the artist himself made it, in which case, that might not be possible. What you could do is just listen to a bunch of different scream samples and find one you like, then pitch it up, or use a sampler. If you're feeling really experimental you could scream into a mic and make your own sample. What software are you using?

Comment: I am currently using FL Studio 12

Answer (score 0):

So like I was saying in the comments. I think this is an FM based synth stab. I started to make one in FM8 (by native instruments). So I have a one oscillator with a slow attack at a 1 ratio and another feeding into it at a 3 ratio, with a slightly faster attack. Then I put on a shelving filter to cut out all the low end, and added a fat reverb on 100% wet. It's pretty close, but could use a bit more tweaking.

[image]

Alternatively, I was thinking that it sounds quite a bit like an electric drill which has been modified. If you go on a free SFX site, you can find an electric drill, EQ out all the low end, add in some reverb, and have a high-pass filter that opens slowly as the sample is played.

Comment: I am using Audio Blocks which is an SFX site and I cannot seem to find that 'electric drill' sound.

Comment: Not a very good site if it doesn't have something that simple haha. Try any of these: https://www.zapsplat.com/sound-effect-categories/, http://www.freesfx.co.uk/, https://www.soundeffectsplus.com/, https://freesound.org/browse/tags/sound-effects/. This is one that has a list of drills, https://freesound.org/search/?q=electric+drill The second or third wav would work well IMO.

Comment: No luck yet but thank you for the help and assistance.

Comment: No luck? I'm sorry if I wasn't descriptive enough or anything. Hope it gets resolved for you!

Comment: No problem at all. I'm some-what new to this thread so I was just curious on what exactly that sound was so I could use it. ;)

Comment: Well welcome to Sound Design!

Comment: Thank you thank you! Hopefully Ill be able to improve soon!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to hear in your example, and I could be wrong, but it sounds like a trumpet or some kind of brass sample drowned in reverb.

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong but to me it sounds like that characteristic stab (in the lack of a better word) from Insane in the membrane from Cypress Hill. Probably pitched up quite a bit.

It would kind of suit the genre as a reference to them if it's that.